# Написание прилагательных, включающих в свой состав числительные

Tags: прилагательные, числительные

Предположим, у меня есть купюра в 123'456'789 зимбабвийских долларов (не хочу предполагать это с рублями). Как её корректно назвать?

В правилах обычно указывают, что писать такие числительные нужно слитно и приводят короткие примеры, такие, как десятидолларовая. А как быть, если требуется образовать подобные сложносоставные прилагательные? Самый длинный пример, что я нашёл, это "тысячадевятьсотвосьмидесятидевятимиллиметровый", и он не из статьи по правописанию.

В [статьях по правописанию](http://lingvotech.com/slitnoe_i_razdelnoe_napisanie_imen_chislitelnih) пишут следующее:

> Составные  числительные необходимо отличать от сложных прилагательных,
>   образованных на основе существительного и числительного; такие
>   прилагательные пишут­ся слитно. Ср.: двадцать пять лет —
>   двадцатипятилет­ний, тридцать три дня — тридцатитрёхдневный.

Но на тему словообразования длинных числительных всё равно остаётся пробел.

Если рассуждать логически, то нам нужно взять числительное в родительном падеже, то есть, в нашем случае, "ста двадцати трёх миллионов четырёхсот пятидесяти шести тысяч семисот восьмидесяти девяти" и написать всё слитно, вместе с "долларовая". Или всё таки правильно будет миллионы и тысячи написать отдельно и добавить через пробел "семисотвосьмидесятидевятидолларовая"?
Получаются два варианта, какой правильный?

1. стадвадцатитрёхмиллионовчетырёхсотпятидесятишеститысячсемисотвосьмидесятидевятидолларовая
2. ста двадцати трёх миллионов четырёхсот пятидесяти шести тысяч семисотвосьмидесятидевятидолларовая

По поводу родительного падежа тоже неясно, потому что считается правильным "стопудовый", но не "стапудовый". Существует ли вообще полное описание проблемы?

Comment: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.43

Comment: По этому справочнику можно ориентироваться,  он совпадает с Розенталем,  только тут все собрано в одной главе. Правильно слитное написание,  как в первом варианте, только "сто" не изменяется, остается в именительном падеже.

Comment: Плюс Розенталь §166. Справочник по русскому языку.

Comment: О каком Розентале идёт речь? Я нашёл только вот этого, там в §40 до наших масштабов не доведено: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=51,4
П.С. Другое издание, §45: http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_x.html#sect45, то же самое.
П.П.С gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.43 - аналогично, нет подробностей.

Comment: Сайт с разъяснениями, возможно, это поможет понять как образуются числительные: https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=cht&chtid=660&subid=150

Answer (score 3):

Правильный вариант:

- сто двадцать три миллиона четыреста пятьдесят шесть тысяч семисотвосьмидесятидевятидолларовая купюра

По аналогии с порядковыми числительными:

- 1,100,000 - один миллион стотысячный
- 1,100,000,000 - один миллиард стомиллионный

Просто заменяем -тысячный, -миллионный на -долларовый.

**Девяносто** и **сто** не склоняются, когда пишутся слитно: стодолларовый, девяностолетний. Это исключение есть почти во всех статьях о правописании порядковых числительных.

Comment: Если не трудно, хотелось бы подтверждения ваших слов, чтобы ваш ответ не был голословным. Тогда можно будет отметить его как правильный.

Answer (score 2):

Язык - это вероятностное пространство, где произнесённые или напечатанные фразы - это случайные события, причём неравновероятные. Это значит, что есть такие слова и выражения, которые можно услышать чаще, есть которые реже, есть и такие, которые на практике точно не встретишь, а встретишь только в искусственно построенных примерах.

Орфография языка не заточена под такие умозрительные примеры. Да, по правилам стадвадцатитрёхмиллионовчетырёхсотпятидесятишеститысячсемисотвосьмидесятидевятидолларова купюра (орфография сохранена - я тут о том, что слитно), ну, собственно, и что?

Нет такой купюры, и никто так не пишет. 
Ваш вопрос сродни вопросу - вот есть прадедушка. А как же назвать предка, жившего 1000 лет назад: Прапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрадедушка что ли? Ха-ха! Хи-хи.

Что же касается почему "стадолларовая" - так это вы просто ошиблись, пишется "стодолларовая" - вот поэтому и "стопудовый".

Comment: Не "Хи-хи", а хотелось бы полного понимания языка. Например, для создания ИИ, верно изъясняющегося по-русски (чат-бот или переводчик). Для этого нужно вычистить все "пыльные углы". И не надо снисходительно относиться к детским вопросам, дети честны, в отличие от взрослых.

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin if your AI will make subtle errors in writing nine-digit numbers as words, not a single person will notice, because there's hardly a single living Russian-speaking person who is able to do the same, or even to verify whether the spelling is right. Therefore this answer is the closest to truth: the best your bot could do is not even try, just leave the number as is.